# Confirmations in block and trasaction

Tags: transactions, block, confirmations

From the bitcoin RPC, both `gettransaction` and `getblock` returns a `confirmation` number in their response, are they always the same? Is there a case a transaction's confirmations isn't the same as its containing block's confirmation number?

```
https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#gettransaction

https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#getblock
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a case a transaction's confirmations isn't the same as its containing block's confirmation number?

No, by definition the number of confirmations on a transaction is the number of confirmations on the block it is contained in.

Comment: So that is a yes? the two confirmations are the same thing?

Comment: Yes, they're the same, by definition.